# How to prove that $\lVert B^{-1} A \rVert$ can be computed as $\sup_{x\in H} \frac {(Ax, x)}{(Bx, x)}$ in infinite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a linear, bounded and symmetric operator $A: H \to H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space. The operator norm of $A$ can be computed as
\begin{align}
\lVert A\rVert = \sup_{x\in H} \frac {(Ax, x)}{(x, x)},
\end{align}
where $(.,.)$ denotes the inner product on $H$. I would like to be able to claim and prove that the norm can also be computed by switching the inner product $(.,.)$ to another inner product $(.,.)_B$ defined for any $x, y \in H$ as
\begin{align}
(x, y)_B = (Bx, y)
\end{align}
where $B: H \to H$ is symmetric, linear, bounded and positive definite. This would allow the computation of $\lVert B^{-1} A \rVert$ as
\begin{align}
\lVert B^{-1} A \rVert = \sup_{x\in H} \frac{(Ax, x)}{(Bx, x)}
\end{align}
in the case when $B$ has a bounded inverse.

It is clear that this holds when $A$ and $B$ are matrices but the proofs I know (using $B^{1/2}$ or reformulation to generalized eigenvalue problem) can not be used on the general level. I'd appreciate any trick or reference that would make this clear for infinite dimensional spaces.